# proc import with tab delimited

Tags: import, sas

I've got the following file I'm trying to import

```
namq_aux_lp         07.07.2014
namq_aux_ulc        08.07.2014
namq_aux_gph        07.07.2014
prc_hicp_cann       17.07.2014
namq_nace10_k       02.07.2014
sei_bsco_m          10.06.2014
ei_bsin_m_r2        26.06.2014
lassei_bsbu_m_r2    26.06.2014
assei_bsrt_m_r2     26.06.2014
ei_bssi_m_r2        26.06.2014
ei_bsse_m_r2        26.06.2014
ei_bsci_m_r2        26.06.2014
sts_trtu_m          17.07.2014
```

I've used the following proc import's

```
proc import out=lesdates datafile="C:\work\studies\project\data\calend\bigfilev2.txt"
dbms=tab REPLACE;
getnames=no;
run;

proc import out=lesdates datafile="C:\travail\etudes\projetpib\donnees\calend\bigfilev2.txt"
dbms=tab REPLACE;
delimiter='09'x;
getnames=no;
run;
```

But each time, instead of having 2 variables, I'm ending with one variable taking the 2 columns

```
             var1
------------------------------
namq_aux_lp         07.07.2014
namq_aux_ulc        08.07.2014
namq_aux_gph        07.07.2014
prc_hicp_cann       17.07.2014
namq_nace10_k       02.07.2014
sei_bsco_m          10.06.2014
ei_bsin_m_r2        26.06.2014
lassei_bsbu_m_r2    26.06.2014
assei_bsrt_m_r2     26.06.2014
ei_bssi_m_r2        26.06.2014
ei_bsse_m_r2        26.06.2014
ei_bsci_m_r2        26.06.2014
sts_trtu_m          17.07.2014
```

What am I doing wrong???

PS: I can edit the text file but I would like to do the import without touching anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a tab delimited text file, from what I can tell (I've never seen 9+ character tabs, so it seems likely).  That's a fixed width format file.  You could in theory use space delimiter, but reading it in as fixed width is better.

```
data want;
 infile "yourfile.txt";
 input
  @1 var1 $20.
  @21 var2 ddmmyy10.
 ;
 format var2 ddmmyy10.;
 run;
```

Comment: Cheers Joe. However, I have for the datatype of var2 , a number instead of a date. Is it normal?

Comment: Add a `format` statement to make it look like a date (the informat means it was read in properly, so it is probably 19153 or something like that, but you still have to format it to look pretty).

Comment: Cheers Joe. Learning , learning. My young colleague says thanks to you.

Comment: I've allowed myself to edit your post with the format.